# Binding Input to Angular controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a shopping cart that shows the name of the flavor and quantity, then the total $ of each flavor. Then at the bottom of all the flavor, I have the calculation of the entire shopping cart.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="flavor in cart track by $index">
 <div>
   <span class="flavor-name no-margin">{{flavor.name}} x <input type="text" name="{{flavor.name}}" size="1" ng-model="flavor.quantity"></span>
   <span class="flavor-price no-margin">{{flavor.price * flavor.quantity | currency }}</span>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div ng-if="cart.length > 0">
  <span class="cart-total-text no-margin">Total:</span>
  <span class="cart-total no-margin">{{ total | currency}}</span>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

In my Controller:

```
function total() {
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cart.length; i++) {
     var add = $scope.cart[i].price * $scope.cart[i].quantity;
     total = total + add;
   }

  return total;
}

$scope.$watchCollection("cart", function() {
  $scope.total = total();
});
```

And my cart looks like this: 
      {
        'name': 'Strawberry',
        'price': 4.5,
    'quantity': 0,
  },
  {
    'name': 'Mint',
    'price': 3.5,
    'quantity': 0,
  }, etc

Right now, the total is working for when I add new things to the cart, but how do I make angular "listen" to when the quantity of the flavor is changed in my input box? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to put the `total()` function on the scope and bind it to the span:

In the HTML:

```
<span class="cart-total no-margin">{{total() | currency}}</span>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.total = function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cart.length; i++) {
        var add = $scope.cart[i].price * $scope.cart[i].quantity;
        total = total + add;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Whenever something changes (like the quantity), Angular should trigger a digest cycle and reevaluate all the bound expressions including the `total()` method.

IMO that's the easiest way. If you really want to go with the $watch route (or understand why your current code is not working) you have to understand how Angular "watches" objects.

- `$scope.$watch` by defaults only fires when the **reference** of the object changes.
- `$scope.$watchCollection` goes a little further and fires when elements are **added or removed** from a collection (even though the collection reference stays the same).

In your case, changing the quantity of a flavor does not add or remove an item in the collection, which is why your code isn't triggered.

What you really want is a "deep watch" of the cart object. That can be achieved by passing a 3rd argument to the `$watch` method (a boolean called `objectEquality`):

```
$scope.$watch("cart", function() {
    $scope.total = total();
}, true); // Tells Angular to test object equality.
```

This will make Angular look for change in the properties of the watched object (not just the reference), which should fire when the flavor.quantity changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch a function if it is in the scope.

```
$scope.$watch('total()', function(){

});
```

Comment: Hello, can you please elaborate a little bit on this? I am an angular noobie. What do I put between the { }? Do I delete the $watch.collection call I already have?

Comment: You can watch any function whether its on the scope or not